# Why doesn't Haibara change her hairstyle?

Tags: detective-conan

Akai, Jodie, and Vermouth notice the similarity between Haibara and Sherry and I think this is mainly due to her hairstyle which she didn't change after her body shrank.

Why doesn't she change it as a disguise?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's in-universe answer regarding this. The reason would be similar with the answer to the question [Why do characters always wear the same clothes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6397/2869)

It's so we can recognize her easily with her older self.

Beside, Aoyama is known for using tons of character. Saving one hairstyle means saving one totally different character. Who know if he will use different hairstyle with Haibara's face for new character that intended to be similar to Haibara for plot reasons. (We know he did for Shinichi and Kid)

Beside she did try to disguise her self several times already. Sometimes she use a cap or Conan's glasses